# Count AVG with double GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

Following SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.browserSessionId, v.visitDay, b.sessionTime 
FROM visit AS v 
INNER JOIN bsession AS b 
ON v.browserSessionId=b.browserSessionId
```

gives me this result:

```
browserSessionId    visitDay    sessionTime     
100                 20150914    150
101                 20150914    100
102                 20150914    50
103                 20150915    75
104                 20150915    150
114                 20150915    225
```

and what I want to have as a result is average sessionTimes grouped by visitDay:

```
visitDay    sessionTime     
20150914    50
20150915    75
```

This query gives me wrong results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.browserSessionId, v.visitDay, AVG(b.sessionTime)
FROM visit AS v 
INNER JOIN bsession AS b 
ON v.browserSessionId=b.browserSessionId
GROUp BY v.visitDay

browserSessionId    visitDay    AVG(b.sessionTime)  
100                 20150914    100.0000
103                 20150915    142.5000
```

Instead of distinct values for every bowserSessionId it counts the average sessionTime of every occurence of browserSession in vist table:

```
SELECT b.browserSessionId, v.visitDay, b.sessionTime 
FROM visit AS v 
INNER JOIN bsession AS b 
ON v.browserSessionId=b.browserSessionId

browserSessionId    visitDay    sessionTime     
100                 20150914    150
100                 20150914    150
100                 20150914    150
101                 20150914    100
101                 20150914    100
101                 20150914    100
101                 20150914    100
102                 20150914    50
102                 20150914    50
102                 20150914    50
103                 20150915    75
103                 20150915    75
103                 20150915    75
103                 20150915    75
104                 20150915    150
104                 20150915    150
104                 20150915    150
114                 20150915    225
114                 20150915    225
114                 20150915    225
```

How to make SQL count only distinct values of sessionTime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use subquery:

```
SELECT t.browserSessionId, t.visitDay, AVG(t.sessionTime)
FROM
(
   SELECT DISTINCT b.browserSessionId, v.visitDay, b.sessionTime 
   FROM visit AS v 
   INNER JOIN bsession AS b 
      ON v.browserSessionId=b.browserSessionId 
) AS t
GROUP BY t.browserSessionId, t.visitDay;
```

Or depending on aggregation level

```
SELECT t.visitDay, AVG(t.sessionTime)
FROM
(
   SELECT DISTINCT b.browserSessionId, v.visitDay, b.sessionTime 
   FROM visit AS v 
   INNER JOIN bsession AS b 
      ON v.browserSessionId=b.browserSessionId 
) AS t
GROUP BY t.visitDay;
```